# Onomatopoeia in "O madness of discourse"

Tags: meaning, onomatopoeia

While writing a commentary for Shakespeare's *Troilus and Cressida*, my classmate and I got into a small quarrel over the classification of an onomatopoeia.

We were wondering, for the line “O madness of discourse”, would *O* (which I guess is equivalent to the more modern *Oh*) be classified as an onomatopoeia? My classmate claims that it’s nothing more than repetition, but I still believe it’s the former.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Onomatopoeia** means that a word *for* a sound *imitates* that sound. For example, **jingle** is the word for a metallic sound, and it imitates that metallic sound.

**O** is not onomatopoeic because it is not the word for the sound *oh*.

Comment: Good answer, I would just add that the word "O" is actually an *interjection*.

Comment: You missed a big bad bit, or a great grand bit, or some such.  See [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/78056/2085).

Answer (score 5):

*O* or *Oh* is simply used as an exclamation. It is not an onomatopoeia since this refers to the property of a word sounding like the sound it is referring to, such as the use of *quack* or *moo*.

Comment: I think Shakespeare's usage as quoted by OP falls into the same "subclass" as, for example, *"Hear me, Oh Lord"*. Where it's an "exclamation" that serves to underline the importance of the word / thing / person following. Which is not quite the same as - oh, I don't know - that one, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

The word *O*, sometimes spelled *Oh*, can as here in the Shakespeare quote above serve as a ***vocative* particle**.  The OED gives its first sense as:

> **1**. Standing before a sb. in the vocative relation.

The etymology is interesting:

> A natural (or what now seems a natural) exclamation, expressive of feeling. OE. had neither *ó!*, nor *á!* (which would have phonetically given ME. *ô!*). Not in OHG., or early ONor.; in Goth., prob. from Greek; in MHG. and later (Christian) Norse, prob. from Latin. In early ME. 12th c., app. from L. (or ? Fr.); but often varying with *A!*, esp. in northern writers. Wyclif has *O* (or A) only when *O* is in the Vulgate. In OE., Lat. *O* was rendered by *lá* or *éalá*.

Colloquial English doesn’t use a vocative *oh* much.  It sounds old-fashioned.

- O Death, where is thy sting?  O Grave, where is thy victory?

But you still find it in poetry, of course:

- 1850 Tennyson *In Mem.* iv. 5 ― O heart, how fares it with thee now?

When spelled *O*, it must be capitalized; when spelled *oh*, it is only capitalized when it falls at the start of a sentence.

There is another, interjective sense of *oh* that we do still use colloquially.

- Oh, I should think so!

The OED says of this second sense:

> **2**. In other connexions, or without construction, expressing, according to intonation, various emotions, as appeal, entreaty, surprise, pain, lament, etc. In this use, in 17th and 18th c., often written **oh** (q.v.); but this form is now usual only when the exclamation is quite detached from what follows (see **oh**); <sup><sub>*O* being used with an imperative, optative, or exclamatory sentence or phrase, as in *O take me back again! O would I were there! O that I might see him! O for another glimpse of it! O the pity of it! O dear me! O dear! O me!;* often also in *O yes, O no, O indeed, O really,* and the like.</sub></sup>

And here are some more Tennyson citations:

- 1842 Tennyson *‘Break, break’* iii, ― O for the touch of a vanish’d hand.
- 1850 Tennyson *In Mem.* xxxv, ― O me, what profits it to put An idle case?